# Jquery - need help for deleting table row

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to delete row (tr) with current button on it

this is my code

```
<td> 
  <button onClick="deleteparticipant({{$participant->id}})" class="deletebutton">Delete</button> 
</td>
```

Script :

```
var token = document.getElementById('_token').value;

      function deleteparticipant(i) {
          alert (i);
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"<?= URL::to('/deleteparticipant')?>",
              dataType:"json",
              data:{
                  'participantid':i,
                  '_token':token
              },

              success: function(data){

                  tr.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                      $(this).remove();
                  });      ==> didnot work :(
              }
          });

      }
```

PHP :

```
public function deleteparticipant(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $_POST['participantid'];

        $participant=participants::find($id);

        $participant->delete();

       return response()->json(['status' => 'done']);

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in `success` callback function is not referred to your current element,you can declare a variable for `this` and remove it in `success` function

```
  function deleteparticipant(i) {
      alert (i);
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var obj = $(this);
      $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"<?= URL::to('/deleteparticipant')?>",
          dataType:"json",
          data:{
              'participantid':i,
              '_token':token
          },

          success: function(data){

              tr.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                 obj.remove();
              });     
          }
      });

  }
```